# Maven not finding Eclipse Plug-in tests

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

So I have a large project and we're just now trying to integrate tests into the whole thing (I know). But when I run a

```
mvn clean install
```

on the test plug in, I get the message

```
All Tests Passed!
```

But its clearly not running the tests since one of my tests is written to fail. The structure of my plug in project is:

```
->src/${filepath}  */ My tests are here
->src/${filepath}/folderA
->src/${filepath}/folder
etc...
```

I have a master pom file a level up which is used to compile all dependencies (successfully). Is my structure just wrong in the test plug in?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<version>1.0.0.qualifier</version>
<artifactId>com.exeeng.test</artifactId>
<packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>
<name>${name}</name>

<parent>
    <version>${parent-version}</version>
    <groupId>${parent-grou}</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
</parent>
<properties>
    <tycho-version>0.19.0</tycho-version>
</properties>   
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-osgi-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: On top of the points mentioned by @Vwin, make sure your test class names either [being with `Test` or end with `Test`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html), or else you will need custom configuration.

Comment: You are talking about Eclipse plugins? Are you using tycho? Would be useful if you showed us your test pom.

Comment: Here is my test POM, the tests all end with Test, so that should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

According to Maven specification, a maven project has tests in src/test/java and its resources in src/test/resources (default). Do you have this structure?

I would like to add that maven Junit tests are run by surefire-plugin which expects this as the default directory structure for tests. If you need to configure this, [check this](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)

Comment: In a simple example I did, this did not have to be the case.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, had quite the busy day yesterday. The Tests do not have to be in src/test/java in order to be found, since the testing is done in a separate plug in. I have a simple example that works where the test is in src/some_stuff/more_stuff/test/SimpleJunitTest.java